# ZK Unsupported parent for row: <Radiogroup nLEPs6>

Tags: java, zk

I have a problem with a grid that uses a model as source that I cannot fix.

In my .zul I have:

```xml
<grid model="@bind(vm.experiments)">
    <columns>
        <column label="Experiment" sort="auto" />
    </columns>
    <template name="model" var="experiment">
        <row>
            <vbox>
                <hbox>
                    <button label="Add ChipSeq Unit" 
                            onClick="@command('addChipSeqUnit', experiment=experiment)">
                    </button>
                    <button label="Delete Experiment"
                            onClick="@command('deleteExperiment', experiment=experiment)">
                    </button>
                    <button label="Edit Experiment"
                            onClick="@command('editExperiment', experiment=experiment)">
                    </button>
                    <radiogroup model="@load(experiment.replicatesFlagValues)"
                                selectedItem="@bind(experiment.replicatesFlag)"
                                hflex="1">
                    </radiogroup>   
                </hbox>
            </vbox>
        </row>
    </template> 
</grid>
```

The method `getExperiments` in the ViewModel returns a List of `CSExperiment` objects. This class' definition is:

```
public class CSExperiment {

    private List<ChipSeqUnit> chipSeqUnits = new LinkedList<ChipSeqUnit>();
    private Integer replicatesFlag;

    public List<ChipSeqUnit> getChipSeqUnits() {
        return chipSeqUnits;
    }

    public void setChipSeqUnits(List<ChipSeqUnit> chipSeqUnits) {
        this.chipSeqUnits = chipSeqUnits;
    }

    public Integer getReplicatesFlag() {
        return replicatesFlag;
    }

    public void setReplicatesFlag(Integer replicatesFlag) {
        this.replicatesFlag = replicatesFlag;
    }

    public List<Integer> getReplicatesFlagValues(){
        return Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{0, 1});
    }

}
```

However, when composing the grid, it says `Unsupported parent for row: <radiogroup nleps6="">`, although apparently it is correctly binded.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Can you please try and create a ZK Fiddle which does?

Comment: Can you post your project or a sample of the project where you will get the fault on dropbox/google drive? I can't reproduce it also so its easier if I can work with a "working" code.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using

`<radiogroup model="@load(experiment.replicatesFlagValues)"
                                selectedItem="@bind(experiment.replicatesFlag)"
                                hflex="1">`

try with `children` like

`<radiogroup children="@load(experiment.replicatesFlagValues)"
                                selectedItem="@bind(experiment.replicatesFlag)"
                                hflex="1">`